# Update database with random entries in Laravel

Tags: database, laravel

I have one table with coordinates (longitude, latitude) and time. 
How could I update that entries, and get them randomly (coordinates should between 44.00000-45.00000, and 16.00000-17.00000, time randomly in last 24 hours), and all that make with button in blade.

Is this thing even posible?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a PHP library called [Faker from fzaninotto](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker).

For time use: [Faker DateTime: dateTime()](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#fakerproviderdatetime).

For coordinates use: [Faker Base: randomFloat()](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#fakerproviderbase)

Comment: I used faker before, but only in database Seeder. Is it posible to use it in Controller or blade?

Comment: Of course! Create a new object, assign values and save. I am not sure about how you would use it in a blade file, but I am certain you can use it in a controller.